# Linq2SQL, use dataContext after Exception

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, exception, datacontext

Here a small piece of code for testing and explain the problem. I have a table Person with 3 fields :

- Id
- FirstName (not nullable)
- LastName (not nullable)

In the loop :

- First : I insert the first row ... normal,
- Second : I try to insert a not correct item, `Exception` ... normal
- Third : I try to insert the third row ... `Exception` (same than for the second) but the values are correct.

Is there something to do to use the same `dataContext` after an `Exception` ?

```
public class MyTestClass
{
    private readonly DataModelDataContext _dataContext;

    public MyTestClass()
    {
        _dataContext = new DataModelDataContext();
    }

    public void InsertList()
    {
        List<Person> liste = new List<Person>();
        liste.Add(new Person { FirstName = "AAA", LastName = "BBBB" });
        liste.Add(new Person { FirstName = string.Empty, LastName = null });
        liste.Add(new Person { FirstName = "CCC", LastName = "DDD" });

        foreach (var item in liste)
        {
            try
            {
                _dataContext.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(item);
                _dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq DataContext doesn't recover after a caught exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470612/linq-datacontext-doesnt-recover-after-a-caught-exception)

Comment: Did you check that your second person is still in the _dataContext.Persons waiting to be insert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataContext` should always be short-lived. You should re-factor your design to achieve this.

You can consider these points:

- Use context per transaction. This way you can make the context short-lived in meaningful way.
- Rollback when your transaction fails. This includes inserting correct item with new transaction. That means, you have a fresh different context now.
- Repeat the process until the transaction completes.
- Again, don't forget to end the context when you are done. This can be easily achieved by making use of the `using` statement.

[Remark from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.aspx):

> The DataContext is the source of all entities mapped over a database
>   connection. It tracks changes that you made to all retrieved entities
>   and maintains an "identity cache" that guarantees that entities
>   retrieved more than one time are represented by using the same object
>   instance.
>
> In general, a DataContext instance is designed to last for one "unit
>   of work" however your application defines that term. A DataContext is
>   lightweight and is not expensive to create. A typical LINQ to SQL
>   application creates DataContext instances at method scope or as a
>   member of short-lived classes that represent a logical set of related
>   database operations.

---

If it takes time to re-factor your design, temporarily you can do like this:

```
    public void InsertList(List<Person> people)
    {
        foreach (var person in people)
        {
            DoInsert(person); 
            // You can use the returned flag and implement the logic if desired.
            // Or let the loop move on its ways.
        }
    }

    public bool DoInsert(Person person)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DataModelDataContext dataContext = new DataModelDataContext())
            {
                dataContext.Persons.InsertOnSubmit(person);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and this is how you can call `InserList` Method:

```
    List<Person> liste = new List<Person>();
    liste.Add(new Person { FirstName = "AAA", LastName = "BBBB" });
    liste.Add(new Person { FirstName = string.Empty, LastName = null });
    liste.Add(new Person { FirstName = "CCC", LastName = "DDD" });

    InsertList(liste);
```